# Bright line on sceen

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I carry my tablet in my bag most of the times and so I did the same today. Only, today, when I got back home I noticed this:

[image]

My screen now has a nasty bright line on the left side. What is it? How would it have happened? Can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hardware issue with the screen; specifically, the light guide.  This is a defect and there isn't anything you can do about it except to replace the screen.

An LCD touchscreen is made up of about 7 very thin layers, the backmost of which is the light guide.  The LEDs that light the screen are along the bezel edge on one or two sides.  The light guide's job is to diffuse that light and spread it uniformly across the screen's surface so that the light appears to be coming evenly from behind, not from visible points along the side.

What you are seeing looks like the guide is slightly peeling and/or separating from the other layers of the screen.  It's kind of unusual to see such a nice, straight line though.  Usually when this happens you see irregularly-shaped voids -- almost like there is water back there or something.  Either way though... it can't be fixed.  You'll either have to replace it or learn to live with it.

Comment: Well, I guess this should be covered by the warranty.. its less than a month old